# Change window of an app while Drag & Drop

Tags: macos, keyboard

Is it somehow possible to change the window within an application with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> (sorry, German keyboard here, I guess it's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (?) on English keyboards) while Drag & Drop something? While it works between different applications it seems not to work within one application with multiple windows. It's especially annoying with small screens and a lot of overlapping windows.

Example 1: Mark text in browser, drag it, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to terminal (mutliple windows), <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> to the terminal window you want to drop the text. This works.

Example 2: Mark text in browser, drag it, try to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> to another browser window. This does not work. Same thing with drag & drop of files between two (overlapping) finder windows. It is possible to do this if you use Exposé, but that's quite slow compared to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>.

It's a really annoying thing which bugs me since years and it's still an issue with OS X 10.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with OS X 10.10 Yosemite, this works as expected!

Answer (score -1):

Might I suggest you use copy-and-paste instead of drag-and-drop?

Comment: Sure, that would work with text and probably other objects. But there are cases where this won't work. For example an image in a website can't (easily) copied-and-pasted, but drag&drop would work.